# Proof of $|x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}| \le \alpha^{\alpha} |x-y|$ for $\alpha \ge 1, x,y\in [0,1]$

Tags: analysis, inequality

I want to prove
$$
 |x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}| \le \alpha^{\alpha} |x-y|
$$
for $\alpha \ge 1$ and $x,y \in [0,1]$. For $\alpha \in \mathbb N$ I already got the proof by using the formulae
$$
 (x^n - y^n) = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + \ldots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})
$$
but I have no idea how to generalize to arbitrary $\alpha \ge 0$, any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:*
$$(x^{\alpha} - \alpha^{\alpha} x)' = \alpha(x^{\alpha-1} - \alpha^{\alpha-1}) < 0.$$

Comment: got solution by some algebra with you hint, thx.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t)= \alpha^{-\alpha}t^\alpha=\left(\frac{t}{\alpha}\right)^\alpha$.

Then $f''(t) = \alpha^{-\alpha +1}(\alpha -1)t^{\alpha-2} \geq 0$ whenever $0<t<1$.

Thus $f$ is convex over $[0,1]$.

For $x \neq y$ let

$$F(x,y)= \frac{f(x) - f(y) }{x-y}.
$$

Show that $\left|F(x,y)\right|\leq 1$ over the region of interest using the convexity of $f$. This will imply your inequality.

Comment: got solution by mean value theorem with you hint, thx.